# using imported classes in main project

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have created a new project and added a separate class file. I'm still learning but why do i get the following errors? I can I use this class? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the class called Region_Drag which doesn't inherit from any other class. In code you are trying to say "Me.KeyDown", but in class you don't have any event called KeyDown which could be handled.

Also Me.Close() provides error because you don't have any Close method presented in a class.

Maybe you should inherit that Region_Drag from some class that provides methods that you need (UserControl?).

Comment: Sweet! I was missing `Inherits Form1` in that class. Thanks for the help.